# CActiveDataProvider with some criteria

Tags: mysql, yii

i want to retrieve all data using CActiveDataProvider from a table.
but i want to join it to other table.

first table(member) consist of : id, account_id, etc, etc
second table(table2) consist of : userid, itemname, etc

member.account_id = table2.userid

i want to retrieve data from member, but if only table2.itemname = 'staff'

how can i realize that ?

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria = ?????? // i don't know what to do
   $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Member', array(
        'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by default the main table will get alias `t` so members will be known as `t` :

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t.account_id = t2.userid'; // define join part here
$criteria->addCondition('t2.itemname = "staff"');

$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Member', array(
    'criteria' => $criteria
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the solution for your question here:

[Using CDbCriteria in the Yii Framework - LarryUllman](http://www.larryullman.com/2013/07/24/using-cdbcriteria-in-the-yii-framework/)